# MVVM - Binding custom object - trouble updating on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using a custom class to keep track of the date in a game since DateTime doesn't allow for fictional setups. I have the class bound  to a `Label` in my window. Upon initialization, it displays fine, but refuses to update when I try to advance the date. In the following property located in the ViewModel, a messagebox confirms that the setter fires, but the value is deemed the same and `RaisePropertyChanged()` is never called:

```
public Date Date
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Date; }
    set
    {
        //Messagebox will display here...
        if (DataManager.Data.Date == value)
            return;
        //...But not here
        DataManager.Data.Date = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
    }
}
```

I've tried taking the if statement out but it still won't update.
I have tried several ways of updating `Date` and none have worked. This is the only way I've been able to get the setter to fire at all (this is called in a command in the ViewModel):

```
Date = Date.AddDays(1);
```

Messageboxes confirm that this is updating the date properly (within the boxes, of course).

Here is the `Date.cs` class in full:

```
public enum Season { Light, Shadow }
public class Date : ObservableObject
{
    #region Members

    private int _day;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _day / 100; }
    }

    public Season Season
    {
        get { return (DayOfYear < 70) ? Season.Light : Season.Shadow; }
    }

    public int DayOfYear
    {
        get { return _day % 100; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public Date(int year, int day)
    {
        _day = (100 * year) + day;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public Date AddDays(int value)
    {
        this._day += value;

        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", DayOfYear, Season, Year);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here's the XAML, maybe it will help. I have tried different binding options; none work.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Date}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="4"
           FontFamily="Pericles"
           FontSize="16"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

At this point I don't know what to do to make `Date` update in the view. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I should have mentioned that I'm using MVVM Light, which is where `ObservableObject` and `RaisePropertyChanged` come in. Also, my ViewModel inherits from MVVM Light's `ViewModelBase`. Other bound properties work without any problems.

**Update:** Per Sniffer's suggestion, `AddDays` now reads:

```
public Date AddDays(int value)
{
    this._day += value;

    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Year);
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Season);
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => DayOfYear);

    return this;
}
```

The UI still doesn't update.

When I call...

```
Date = Date.AddDays(1);
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Date.ToString());
```

...inside the command, the Label doesn't change, but the MessageBox displays the updated date correctly.

**Update + Possible Solution:** I have managed to get things working.

In the ViewModel:

```
public string Date
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Date.ToString(); }
}
```

...and in the command

```
DataManager.Data.Date.AddDay(1);
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
```

In `Date.cs`:

```
public void AddDay(int value)
{
    this._day += value;
}
```

Raising properties isn't necessary with this method and `Date` doesn't even have to be observable. Given this information, if anybody could suggest improvements, I'm all ears. If not I'll call it a day with this.

Comment: i see that `Date` inherits from Observable but i don't see you raising any PropertyChanged events in the `Date` class itself ?

Comment: You might also want to rethink your naming conventions.

Comment: What is the implementation of `RaisePropertyChanged()`? Does your view model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Also, if you want to compare dates you'll probably want to implement either `IEquatable<T>` or `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged` is via MVVM Light.

Comment: @JonahKunz What's wrong with the naming?

Comment: @JasonD Date Date is wrong because it could create some trouble if you name your object like your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think your XAML code does?

```
<Label Content="{Binding Date}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="4"
           FontFamily="Pericles"
           FontSize="16"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

the output will properly something like `89 Shadow 900` but thats the wrong way to do it becaus it used your `toString()` this is not bindable AFAIK

but you have still 2 other options

**First one**

create an new property in your Date

```
public string dateString
{
    get { return this.ToString(); }
} // don't forget to raise it in your addDate
```

XAML binding part

```
<Label DataContext="{Binding Date}" Content="{Binding dateString}"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="4"
       FontFamily="Pericles"
       FontSize="16"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

**Second**

use Mutlibinding

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Date}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat='{}{0} {1}, {2}'>
            <Binding Path='DayOfYear' />
            <Binding Path='Season' />
            <Binding Path='Year' />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Adding and raising the string property works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because although your `Date` class implements `Observable` but it doesn't raise any `PropertyChangedEvent`s for any property on the `Date` class. So your view will be only updated if you set the Date Property completely assigning it a new Date like this: `Date = new Date(2013, 69);` for example, to fix this you need to raise PropertyChangedEvent for each property in your `Date` and those are `Year, DayOfYear, Season`.

Comment: Using the MVVM Light framework, how would I do this without creating variables for each (for the setters)?

Comment: @JasonD, you don't need a setter for each property to do that. in each location that causes modification to those properties, call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => PROPERTY_NAME)`, for example in your `AddDays()` method, when you add days you need to raise property changed evet for `DayInYear` and any other affected property, i hope you get the idea.

Comment: I've done that now; all 3 are raised in `AddDays()` and the UI still isn't updating.

Comment: @JasonD, i don't know what to tell you, something is missing, double check your code.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet in your question shows that the `Label` is bound to the `Date` property, not to the individual properties of the date. The UI has no way of knowing that the contents of the date changed.

It sounds like you need to add `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date)` somewhere in your view model, but without seeing more of your code it's hard to say where to put it. Maybe after the call to `AddDays()`?

Comment: I've tried calling `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date)` in the command directly after `AddDays()` with no luck. I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the getter for Date, does it trigger after the `RaisedPropertyChanged()` call?

Answer (score 0):

DataManager.Data.Date what is this? you just post the Date class, but that makes no sense in your setter and getter, so i assume thats a property in your Data object? if yes then pls post this property - and if this proeprty call onpropertychanged in the setter your binding should work

EDIT: i read more carefully now :) you bind to the Date class and you want to see changes when .AddDays(1) is called? if you dont bind directly to year, day and month you should try to update the datacontext for your label. this of course dont work when you wanna see changes on AddDays()- it would just work if you set a new Date Property.

```
<Label DataContext="{Binding Date}" Content="{Binding .}"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.Column="4"
       FontFamily="Pericles"
       FontSize="16"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

but if you would bind directly to year, day and month - you should call onpropertychanged on each and use a multiconverter.

the problem is that you bind to a Date object and wanna see changes when something inside the date object changes (eg. with AddDays(1)) thats not working the way you do it.

Comment: I can explain bad in english sorry :)